# Sodium Citrate / Sodium Phosphate Buffer Calculations

Tags: physical-chemistry, aqueous-solution, biochemistry, buffer, henderson-hasselbalch-equation

I'm trying to work through the calculations of a specific paper ([linked here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.langmuir.1c02889) / below) but, my numbers are way off and I can't get them to match for the life of me. I need to make the same buffer but at a lower concentration. I'm not understanding how the paper was able to get the ratios (found in supplementary information) they used to make the buffer.

For example:
0.9M phosphate/citrate buffer, pH 3
Ratios used:  disodium hydrogen phosphate (0.87g/100mL); trisodium citrate dihydrate buffer (3.51g/100mL)

How were they able to calculate those ratios? I've tried using Henderson-Hasselback equation but maybe I'm utilizing it incorrectly?

Comment: Those components are not able to reach pH 3. pH would be > 7. // BTW, questions should be self-contained, answerable without following any link, that should serve just as a reference to content origin, or for further reading for better context.

Answer (score 2):

Those components are not able to reach $\text{pH 3}$ without addition of an acid, as both salts gives solutions with alkalic pH values.

---

At such high concentrations near $\pu{1 M}$, pH calculations are off, unless going a long, long way of experimental determining activity coefficients (as these cannot be reliably predicted for such concentrations either).

pH of such buffers cannot be calculated from basic principles like via the [Henderson-Hasselbalch equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henderson%E2%80%93Hasselbalch_equation). At the best it can be obtained from published empirical functions or tables of mixing ratios for desired pH.

If no such empirical help is available, the $\pu{pH}$ of such buffers must be adjusted experimentally, using pH meter calibrated on standard pH buffers.